# How to create a Warning Window Message Box in C# like in JavaScript

Tags: c#, wpf, window, alert

For JavaScript, to create a window alert, the code is window.alert("..."), but what is the code for this in C#? I thought it was MessageBox.Show("..."), but it isn't. Please and thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that includes the context in which you want to do this? That will help identify why it isn't working, e.g. if you're trying to do this in an MVC controller.

Comment: I'm curious.  Someone just voted this question up.  I can't imagine why.  There may be a question lurking somewhere behind the curtains, but there isn't one to see at the moment.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I know the OP added an answer that included a WPF reference, but Flydog57 raises an excellent question: shouldn't that reference have already been there? I'm still concerned that it might be a web application, and it works in IISExpress in user space but will totally fail when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it IS MessageBox.Show... MessageBox.Show("Test"); works quite well...

Answer (score -1):

using System.Windows
Once you've done that you'll be able to implement the MessageBox class. If not, then you'll need to do the following:

Open Solution Explorer
Right Click Reference Folder
Add Reference
Go to Assemblies
Go to Browse
Navigate to: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework
Reference PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: What?  How do you know that this is a WPF application.  And, if it's a WPF application, why isn't the PresentationFramework assembly included in the initial set of references.

Comment: @Flydog57, because the answerer is the asker . But that make no sense.